# Loading an object from the database in each request in Laravel using a Middleware, (Performance perspective)

Tags: performance, laravel, caching, menu

I'm trying to implement a form in laravel which manages the menu items dynamically, and I found this great package:

[lavary/laravel-menu](https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu)

So, what I'm gonna do is applying a middleware on all routes in the application, in that middleware, I'll load the serialized/JSONed object from the database and use this sample of code as a guideline to load the menu and make it available to all application pages:

```
Menu::make('MyNavBar', function($menu){

  $menu->add('Home');
  $menu->add('About',    'about');
  $menu->add('services', 'services');
  $menu->add('Contact',  'contact');

});
```

In addition to that I'm thinking of caching the menu object coming from the DB to enhance the performance.

Is there a better way to accomplish this ? (from all perspectives, especially performance).

Thanks.

Comment: include the menu partial into ur master layout then use view composer to handle the menu items ..etc (better than middleware , then use a model observer and caching to handle this , this is just the general idea

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja
Then, do you mean that using the view composer will make the menu object available only whenever the menu template is loaded ? 
And the model observer will change the cache ONLY when the menu is updated, which will improve the performance ?
But where will I load the menu object from the cache/DB ?

Comment: the menu object will be available in anypage you choose, check view composers docs and exemples (sorry i can't provide code since i a bit busy) `$value = Cache::remember('users', 60, function() { put logic here
    return $menu_object;
});`  this way you will retrieve from cache if it's available in cache, if not it will execute the query then cache it for 60 minutes, you can cache it forever and implement model observers

Answer (score 1):

Create a new view that will contain the menu object

**menu.blade.php**

Include the menu inside every view you want to use or inside your master layout file(if you will use it in all of your views)

inside master.blade.php (or whatever you call it/or other view)

```
@include('menu')
```

Set up a view composer (i suppose you know how)

and do it like so

```
     public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(['menu'], function ($view) {
        //you can do it for multiple view
        $menu = Cache::remember('MyNavBar', 60, function () {
            return Menu::make('MyNavBar', function ($menu) {
                $menu->add('Home');
                $menu->add('About', 'about');
                $menu->add('services', 'services');
                $menu->add('Contact', 'contact');
            });
        });
        $view->with('menu', $menu);
    });
}
```

This will make the menu loades with the menu partials and it will be retrieved from cache, if it does not exist in cache, it will be loaded from database then cached for 60 minutes (you can change this ofc)

This is just to give you a general idea , this is my opinion on how you should handle this, someone else might have a better solution so i hope this helps you

MORE ABOUT [VIEW COMPOSERS](https://laracasts.com/lessons/view-composers)

Comment: Thanks!

But the caching section needs to be added in the model observer not in the view composer, right ? or in both ?

Comment: it depends on the project, i dont know , this answer will give you a good result but the issue in the answer it self that changes will be affected only each 60 minutes, you can use model observers or if you need a simple approach , add this on the functions that will update the menu content `Cache::forget('MyNavBar');`